# Harshuf -- Artichoke Stalks

Tags: artichokes

I come from a Moroccan background where they prepare a dish call 'Harshuf'. The name is from the main ingredient stalks of the artichoke plant. It is cooked with lemon and chicken.

Does anyone know what artichoke stalks are called in the US?

Comment: @Andrew - in the past "where can I find..." type of questions have been closed as too localized.  Asking about names for artichoke stalks across the world would be on-topic, but as this question stands I think it may be closed.

Comment: Do you have a link to a recipe? I'm just curious, no bearing on the question. My googling has been unsuccessful - though your question is at the top of the list!

Comment: @justkt: I have modified the question to be on-topic?

Comment: @Jefromi: I do not have a recipe on line. It is a traditional family recipe.

Comment: Is [cardoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardoon) what you're looking for? It's very closely related to artichokes, and is grown for the stalks. Availability may still be a problem - it's not common, but it's definitely out there. I know my grandmother manages to find it in grocery stores here (Texas) with reasonable frequency.

Comment: @Jefromi. Yes it does look like cardoon is what I am looking for. I will add an answer to that effect. -- Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cardoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardoon) is what I am looking for. Thanks to [Jefromi](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/1672/jefromi) for supplying the answer in the comments.

P.S. from Jefromi: according to the Wikipedia article linked above, it's also called artichoke thistle, cardone, cardoni, carduni or cardi.

Answer (score 0):

The correct name of Harshuf in English is Cardone. It's usually sold in farmer's markets. Here is a website where you might be able to get it: www.oceanmist.com.